# How to call a Restful service, which is having a parameter which can have comma?

Tags: query-string, restful-url

I have Restful service which I am trying to call, with some querystring parameters.

The Rest URL looks like

**http://localhost/myservice/offers/postCode/560087/?Id=1&City=Hello,world**

In the above Url , my last query string parameter City can have commas.

I am trying to call service from **Advanced Rest Client** Add-on on Chrome.

But I am getting 406 Not acceptable.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

change the comma with `%2C`, that should do the trick. use [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for future reference. However, are you sure that the 406 is about the comma in the parameter? A 406 is usually returned by REST services when the 'Accept' header has the wrong media-type.

Comment: %2C, doesn't work, and yes i start getting 406 only after started trying for a querystring with comma

Comment: well, that is the standard encoding for commas in urls. It should work, if the service is standard-compliant. Can you debug the service and see what's receiving?